# Converging Locally Uniformly (Complex Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Show that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$ converges locally uniformly in the unit disc. Find the value of $f'''(0)$.

I know the definition of converging locally uniformly but I am not sure how to apply it to the given summation. also I am not sure how to get $f'$ let alone $f'''$

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be the open unit disk and $K\subset D$ a compact set. Let $r\in(0,1)$ be such that $K\subset\{z:|z|\le r\}$. Then
$$
\Bigl|\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}\Bigr|\le\frac{r^n}{1-r^n}\le\frac{r^n}{1-r}\quad\forall z\in K.
$$
Since $0<r<1$, $\sum r^n<\infty$, and by the Weierstrass test the series converges uniformly on $K$. Since each $z^n/(1-z^n)$ is analytic in $D$, the sum $f$ is also analytic. Moreover,
$$
f'''(0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d^3}{dz^3}\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}\Bigr|_{z=0}.
$$
Since
$$
\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}=z^n+z^{2n}+\dots
$$
we see that if $n\ne1$ or $n\ne3$ then
$$
\frac{d^3}{dz^3}\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}\Bigr|_{z=0}=0.
$$
This allows an easy calculation of $f'''(0)$.

Comment: If a sequence $(g_n)_n$ of analytic functions, each analytic on the open unit disc $C,$ converges uniformly  to $g$ on any compact subset of $ C,$ then by the Cauchy-Reimann integral formulas, $g$ is analytic on $C$  and $(g'_n)_n$ converges uniformly  to $g'$ on any compact subset of $ C.$ Applying this again to the sequence $(g'_n)_n$ we get a similar result for $ g'',$ etc.(& for $g''',$...). In particular let $g_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^nz^j/(1-z^j).$